# How to add labels to x-axis when using nplot from the rChart package

Tags: r, rcharts

I have tried

```
require(rCharts); library(datasets); library(knitr); library(tidyverse)

loan_data_set <- read_csv("loan_data_set.csv")

loandata = as.data.frame(loan_data_set)

loandata$Gender <- as.factor(loandata$Gender)

loandata$Married <- as.factor(loandata$Married)

loandata$Education <- as.factor(loandata$Education)

# created a nPlot object

n1 <- nPlot(ApplicantIncome ~ Education, group = 'Married', type = 'multiBarChart', data = loandata)
```

This gives me the following graph

[image]
However, I do not know why the labels to the x-axis do not appear

Comment: Please provide the data in `dput()` format.

Comment: It is a large data file so I hope the structure will make this problem reproducible. Thank you for your help. 
str(loandata)
'data.frame': 614 obs. of  13 variables:

 $ Gender           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

 $ Married          : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...

 $ Education        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Graduate","Not Graduate": 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...

 $ ApplicantIncome  : num  5849 4583 3000 2583 6000 ...

Comment: Maybe because you're trying to show the data with the wrong type of graph - and the function knows this! The outcome (`ApplicantIncome`) appears to be continuous, so a boxplot may be a better choice than a barchart.